# Handling POST Responses

Tags: java, json, yelp

I'm currently playing around with the Yelp Fusion API to retrieve business information.  So far I've been able to get the responses to my POST requests but can only get the whole JSON like output.  Is there any method that will allow me to filter my results?  So just to retrieve a specific key, and value in the JSON output.  My code so far is shown below:

```
try {
        String req = "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?";
        req += "term=" + term + "&location=" + location;
        if(category != null) {
            req += "&category=" + category;
        }
        URL url = new URL(req);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + ACCESSTOKEN);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        String inputLine = reader.readLine();
        buffer.append(inputLine);
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());


        reader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Connecting");
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Roll your own! You cannot change the level of detail the response gives you (unless the API has this functionality), but you can of course filter out what you don't need from the response.

To illustrate, I took [this](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/get_started) response.

```
{
  "terms": [
    {
      "text": "Delivery"
    }
  ],
  "businesses": [
    {
      "id": "YqvoyaNvtoC8N5dA8pD2JA",
      "name": "Delfina"
    },
    {
      "id": "vu6PlPyKptsT6oEq50qOzA",
      "name": "Delarosa"
    },
    {
      "id": "bai6umLcCNy9cXql0Js2RQ",
      "name": "Pizzeria Delfina"
    }
  ],
  "categories": [
    {
      "alias": "delis",
      "title": "Delis"
    },
    {
      "alias": "fooddeliveryservices",
      "title": "Food Delivery Services"
    },
    {
      "alias": "couriers",
      "title": "Couriers & Delivery Services"
    }
  ]
}
```

If we were only interested in businesses that have Delfina in their names, we could do the following.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray businessesArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("businesses");
for (int i = 0; i < businessesArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject businessObject = businessesArray.getJSONObject(i);
    if (businessObject.get("name").toString().contains("Delfina")) {
        //Do something with this object
        System.out.println(businessObject);
    }
}
```

which outputs (as expected)

```
{"name":"Delfina","id":"YqvoyaNvtoC8N5dA8pD2JA"}
{"name":"Pizzeria Delfina","id":"bai6umLcCNy9cXql0Js2RQ"}
```

I made use of the `org.json` package here, which is a very simple one but is sufficient to get you started!